# How do I insert/update/delete individuals with Jena SDB keeping maximum performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, sparql, jena

Recently I switched from the OWL API to Jena in the hope that the performance regarding the insertion and querying of data would increase.

So I started by loading my OWL ontology into a MySQL-based triple-store using Jena SDB. Therefore I used

```
model.read("owl-concepts.turtle")
```

Jena creates about 1500 nodes within the triple store (in the Mysql-table). Initially I was surprised a little bit about the high number of nodes. But this seems reasonable as the OWL ontology contains approximately 80 OWL classes with several data and object properties.

To read data (individuals) from the ontology I leveraged the Jena SDB interface. I retrieved a model and based on the model an ontModel. I used that ontModel to modify individuals, for instance:

```
ontModel.createIndividual(...);
ontModel.getIndividual(....);
individual.remove();
```

For the ontModel i used OWL_MEM; according to the documentation this should mean that no reasoning is applied.

I realized that, based on the described approach, the modification of individual(s) data is not as fast as I expected. On the average the insertion of a simple individual takes between 2 and 30 seconds.

So I started asking: Is using the model interface in Jena the recommended way of modifying data or does this approach has low performance and instead SPARQL should be used for the modification of data? My original plan was to use SPARQL only for the querying part...

Would be thankful for every expert opinion or your experience with Jena.

Comment: Jena TDB is faster than Jena SDB.

Answer (score 0):

Using a persistent triple store -- particularly SDB -- with a reasoner is not a good idea. Reasoners often perform a large number of random accesses on the database, each of which has a little overhead. Once you add them up things get slow.

Similarly, use SPARQL rather than the model or ontology API, since you generate lots of small accesses again.

Given the size of your data this probably fits in memory comfortably, so do that. You can always move the data en mass from and too the SDB store to persist it.

Comment: However, @user1690752 said that he's _not_ using a reasoner.

Answer (score 0):

For just loading,

```
        store.getLoader().startBulkUpdate();
        ...
        store.getLoader().flushTriples();
```

(where `store` is the SBD store object)
but if you are adding and deleting, it's difficult to speed up.

One approach is read all the data into memory, work there, and put it all back.  You can do this with the data severed by Fuseki, and using the graph store protocol part of SPARQL.  You can use any storage backend.